# How to add existing project using environment variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, environment-variables, usb-drive

I have a a project that resides on a "thumb drive" (a.k.a. memory stick).  Due to Windows ability to change drive letters of thumb drives, I would like to specify the location of sub-projects using an environment variable.  This allows me to set the thumb drive drive letter, depending on the PC that I am using; or change the variable when the drive letter changes (such as happens when adding a hard drive to the PC).

This issue has sub parts:

1. How do I tell Visual Studio (2008) to use environment variable *when adding an existing project using the GUI*?
2. Which files do I need to modify with the environment variable (*.dcp, *.vcproj, *.sln)?
3. Do I need to delete the platform specific `vcproj` files, such as `*.vcproj.`*host_name*?
   {Since I use different host PCs with the thumb drive, there are different `vcproj` files.}

I am using MS Visual Studio 2008, C++, on Vista and Windows XP (at least two platforms).

Comment: Incidentally, you can use Disk Manager to assign a specific drive letter (try >= M:) to your specific **volume** -- or mount it to a directory on one of your main NTFS partitions.

Comment: That only works if it's a _proper_ USB device, with a serial number. This breaks with fakes without serial numbers.

Comment: Assigning drive letters is not the issue; it's Windows automagically moving them.  For example, if my thumb drive is "F:" and I add a hard drive (external or internal), my thumb drive will be "G:" rather than the hard drive being assigned to "G:".  I then have to reassign all the drives or just change an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is to use *relative* paths for your subprojects. The relative path from your solution file to the subprojects does not change, as both are on the same thumb drive.

Comment: If this is the best solution, how do I make the GUI "Add Existing Projects" using relative addressing?  Also, where is the "point of reference" for relative addressing?

Answer (score 0):

You can also overcome the wandering drivename by using the 'subst' command.

for instance

```
f(thumbdrive):\>  subst z: projectfolder
```

and then you can always access your folder at z:\, presuming none of the computers have a 'z:' drive installed.

Comment: Although I have not tested this, I know that on Windows XP, adding a hard drive will bump up drive letters and without any concern to network drive mappings.  If I have a network share at "D:" and I add a hard drive, the hard drive becomes "D:" *AND* my network share is still mapped to "D:".  My understanding is the `subst` is along the same lines as mapping a network drive.